# Asp Web Api Breeze in layered application

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I currently have an ASP Web API project and the goal is to create a SPA.

I'm using EF Code first and have the following solution structure:

```
- BookClub.Entities
- BookClub.DataAccess (DbContext, generic Repository, ...)
- BookClub.BusinessLogic (UOW, Facade pattern)
- BookClub.Web (ASP Web Api (v2))
```

I would like to give Breeze a try but I don't really know what would fit where.
All the examples use a Context or Repository in the ApiController.
This should be avoided and per entity a BusinessLogic layer Facade should be used.
But how would my Controller look like then?

Has anyone ever done this before?

Comment: one possible solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969743/breeze-efcontextprovider-breeze-controller-and-service-layer/20972463#20972463

Answer (score 0):

Your controller just facilitates the conversion of your business logic entities for the views you define. If you have build up a business layer then simply use it in the controllers get/put methods. The code below would return a `Book` in json format.

```
[HttpGet]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
public ActionResult GetBook(int bookID)
{
    BookBL bookBL=new BookBL();
    Book model=bookBL.SelectOne(bookID);
    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

//Return a partial view instead 
[HttpGet]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
public ActionResult GetBookView(int bookID)
{
    BookBL bookBL=new BookBL();
    Book model=bookBL.SelectOne(bookID);
    return PartialView("Partials/BookView", model);
}
```

Comment: Doh! just realized you might be referring to controllers in js. This may not be the intended answer.

Comment: No I'm not referring to the controller in js. The question is about using an unit of work structure in conjunction with breezejs. All the samples of breezejs use a single repository, is this just the way to go or how can I further create separation of concerns with an additional bussiness logic layer?

Comment: As said, the controller is a mediator and need not have any business logic. Use repo or UOW patterns behind it as you would in any web API technology. This is NOT a breeze issue at all. Breeze takes what the controller fives it. On the server the ContextProvider is simply a helper with no web API dependency.